# How to find a certain string in a mixed cell array and replace it with an integer?

Tags: string, matlab, comparison, cell-array

I have a mixed cell array with strings and integers. For example:

```
myData = {'blank'      'a'     'b'    'c'; ...
          'sample1'    5       6      'NF'; ...
          'sample2'    'NF'    54     'NF'};
```

I want to go in this cell array, find all instances of `'NF'` and turn it into a `0`.

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution using `strcmp`

```
myData(strcmp(myData,'NF'))={0}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) and [`isequal`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isequal.html):

```
myData(cellfun(@(c) isequal(c, 'NF'), myData)) = {0};
```

Or you could use [`strcmp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) as [Jon suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45982574/52738):

```
myData(strcmp(myData, 'NF')) = {0};
```

*However*, It should be noted that these two solutions aren't *exactly* equivalent in every case. From [the documentation for `strcmp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html#btwfzf5-4):

> The `strcmp` function is intended for comparison of text. If used on unsupported data types, `strcmp` always returns `0`.

So, if either input argument is a data type other than a character vector/array, cell array of character vectors, or string array, `strcmp` will return `false`. Conversely, `isequal` ignores the data type of the input arguments in determining whether they are equal. For example, the numeric vector `[78 70]` is the ASCII equivalent of the character vector `'NF'`, so you get the following results from `strcmp` and `isequal`:

```
>> strcmp([78 70], 'NF')

ans =
  logical

   0       % No match

>> isequal([78 70], 'NF')

ans =
  logical

   1       % Match
```

In other words, `strcmp` is much stricter when comparing the equality of different data types, whereas `isequal` is more lax, allowing for inputs of different data types to be considered equal when their underlying data is effectively the same. You should consider which behavior is desired before choosing a solution.

Comment: My goodness thank you so much. This is such a simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

A double for loop can solve this:

```
for j=1:size(myData,1)
    for k=1:size(myData,2)
        if strcmp(myData{j,k},'NF')
           myData{j,k}=0;
        end
    end
end
```

where `size(myData,1)` finds the number of rows and `size(myData,2)` finds the number of columns of your mixed cell array.